# Roslyn bin folder generated at c:\bin\roslyn

Tags: c#, nuget, roslyn

I've taken over maintenance of a web solution that contains a number of c# projects. On compilation one project creates the Roslyn bin folder under it's output directory bin folder as expected, another however creates the Roslyn bin folder in C:\bin\roslyn. I've searched the project files for any clues as to why this is happening but cannot find any reference to it. In the build log it shows that when the project that creates the Roslyn folder under it's output dir, the files are copied with an absolute destination path (C:\project output dir\bin\Roslyn), whereas in the project that creates it under C:\bin\Roslyn, the files are listed as just copied to \bin\Roslyn. Should a project setting point to the output directory ($(OutputDir) is set). Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, are there any problems currently? maybe you don't even need them... I mean, if it's only used by the websolution, and this one already has them in the bin folder, then the second one clearly doesn't need them. If the project that copies it to the c drive is working, you could safely remove the copying, if it not working outputdir sound like a good idea

Comment: You can probably get better answers by showing whether your `$(WebProjectOutputDir)` property is set, and whether your `$(OutputPath)` property is `\bin` instead of `bin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers, Icepickle is correct in questioning if there is a problem, the solution works but there is just a redundant folder placed off the root drive so it's not ideal. I have sorted the problem by going through the solution build (in Diagnostic Verbosity), and in all the projects that are copying files to the root folder I added the following in their project files. This points to the correct path and will only copy if the files aren't already there.

```
<Target Name="CopyRoslynCompilerFilesToOutputDirectory" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
<ItemGroup>
  <RoslynFiles Include="$(CscToolPath)\*" />
</ItemGroup>
<MakeDir Directories="$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName)\bin\roslyn" />
<Copy SourceFiles="@(RoslynFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName)\bin\roslyn" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)" RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know of 3 ways to investigate MSBuild issues:

In general, I found binary logs (binlogs) to be most useful. Create one by passing the `-bl`, then open  the generated file in the [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com/). It shows very similar data to the build log, but has a good search and shows what happened in a tree view that greatly helps understanding.

What I think will probably be of most use to you for this specific issue is outputting the pre-processed file by running `msbuild -pp` or `dotnet msbuild -pp`. This basically finds all MSBuild `Import` statements, and replaces them with the actual contents of the imported file. I believe that MSBuild always evaluates top-down. So if property1 is defined, then is used to evaluate property2, then later property1 changes, the value of property2 will retain its value from when it was evaluated. Keep in mind that execution of targets cause the target to be evaluated, so it can use a property that was defined further down the file, as long as the lower down target was run first, or the properties or items defined further down are global (not in a target).

Finally, if all else fails, you can try setting the log output to the highest verbosity, diagnostic. Note that `msbuild -v:d` is detailed verbosity, you need `msbuild -v:diag` to set diagnostic verbosity. I'm not sure if this actually outputs anything more than what's in the binlog, but I think there might have been one or two times I was desperate and the diag output helped (but I can't remember if I used the binlog in those occasions). Anyway, worth a try if the other two methods above don't help.